# Django get str instead of date when annotate models.DateField

Tags: python, django, django-models

i have models below

```
class TaskPackage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    task_package = models.ManyToManyField(TaskPackage)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

when i annotate like this, i got **start_date** as str type

```
>>> packages = TaskPackage.objects.annotate(
...     start_date=Min("task__start_date", filter=Q(task__is_deleted=False))
... )
>>> print(type(packages[0].start_date))
<class 'str'>
```

but when i remove Q expression, **start_date** is date type

```
>>> packages = TaskPackage.objects.annotate(
...     start_date=Min("task__start_date")
... )
>>> print(type(packages[0].start_date))
<class 'datetime.date'>
```

Comment: Can you try `Min("task__start_date", output_field =models.DateField(), filter=Q(task__is_deleted=False)`?

Comment: i tried, still get str

Answer (score 0):

My colleague has identified the reason. When using MIN and CASE WHEN, the MySQL server returns an incorrect column type. It should be of date type (with a value of 10) instead of string type (with a value of 253)